# Improve sql query

Tags: sql

Please help to improve the following query:

```
UPDATE queries q 
   SET query = (SELECT q1.query 
                  FROM queries q1 
                 WHERE q1.table_name = q.table_name 
                   AND q1.name = 'View1')
 WHERE q.NAME = 'View2' 
   AND q.table_name IN ('companies', 'persons');
```

Structure of my queries table:

```
table_name  query  name
-------------------------
companies   1      View1
persons     2      View1
companies   3      View2
persons     4      View2
```

ps: I expect it can be done via standard sql syntax, without specific database server features.

pps: Purpose of the task: the "query" field of table_name should be the same for both "name" View1 and View2.

For example, at the moment for companies the "query" of View1 = 1, query of View2 = 3, for persons these values are 2 and 4.

I want to update records by the only sql query so for companies for both View1 and View2 the "query" value should be 1 and for persons for both View1 and View2 the "query" value should be 2.

Comment: Improve how? Does it not alter the data the way you expect? Does it not perform well?

Comment: The way you've written the query seems entirely sensible.  If performance is an issue, you might need to add appropriate indexes.  In that case, start by making sure there is an index on table_name, since that's the field you're joining on.

Comment: I've updates my question, hope, it's more clear now

Comment: @Alexandr - Given your update and given that you only want to standardized SQL, the only change I would make would be to remove the alias used in the Update clause (i.e., `Update queries` instead of `Update queries q`. Beyond that, the way you have formed your query should work fine.

Comment: @Thomas, in this case my subquery cannot filter by: "q1.table_name = table_name", cause it thinks that the "table_name" is the field of queries q1 table, but not outer queries table that is used without alias. This subquery returns multiple records, as a result update fails:(

Comment: @Alexandr - So it sounds like the issue is a syntax problem. I've posted an answer which addresses that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you are having trouble referencing the updated table from within the subquery especially when you remove the alias in the Update clause. To do that, just use the full name of the update table. Notice I used `queries.table_name` and I removed the alias from the Update clause (so `Update queries` instead of `Update queries q`).

```
Update queries
Set query = (
            Select q1.query 
            From queries q1
            Where q1.table_name = queries.table_name
                And q1.name = 'View1'
            )
Where q.NAME = 'View2' 
    And q.table_name IN ('companies', 'persons');
```

Comment: it works, thank you, the only change i've made removed alias from the last "where" clause: Where queries.NAME = 'View2' 
    And queries.table_name IN ('companies', 'persons');